# Which operating system is the most maintained and has no non-free software?

Tags: linux, open-source, linux-distribution, operating-system

I used Debian [until they voted to include non-free code in their installer last year](https://www.debian.org/vote/2022/vote_003). The thing I loved about Debian is that it seemed to be actively maintained and the [`non-free` and `non-free-firmware` archive areas](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#listofdebianarchivearea) were not included in the default installation.

Which 100 % free / libre operating system (doesn't have to be Linux) is the most maintained now?

There are a [few active libre options mentioned on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#General) and GNU.org but it's hard to tell which one is the most actively maintained.

- [Dragora GNU/Linux-Libre](http://www.dragora.org/en/index.html)
- [Guix System](https://guix.gnu.org/)
- [LibreCMC](https://librecmc.org/)
- [PureOS](https://pureos.net/)
- [Trisquel GNU/Linux](https://trisquel.info/)
- [Hyperbola GNU/Linux-libre](https://www.hyperbola.info/) (seems like they're transitioning to HyperbolaBSD)
- [Parabola GNU/Linux-libre](https://www.parabola.nu/)

There also appears to be libre "spins" to some non-free distributions, like [Gnuinos](https://gnuinos.org/) which is a libre spin on the non-libre Devuan. So it's difficult to get a complete list of these operating systems.

Which libre / 100% free operating system is the most supported and updated?